# Powershell script to change Existing date & add 1 hour to it

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file with one of the column headers named *Timeraised*.
I want to add 1 hour to the dates in this column.
For example, if the date in the *Timeraised* column is 09-04-202 **05**:12 then it should change to 09-04-202 **06**:12

I tried below commands but it just changing the time format.

Import-Csv $CSVLoc\Alert.csv | % {$*.TimeRaised = (datetime).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy h:mm');$*} | 
Export-Csv $CSVLoc\alert1.csv -NoTypeInformation

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stack overflow . kindly try to solve the above yourself and whenever you face difficulty in doing so please post the **script** along with the difficulty you face. read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a clear idea on how to ask a question.

Comment: What have you tried yet? Please share that code and explain what didn't work so we can help you. For starters, you will need to look into [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv), [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv), [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact) and [DateTime.AddHours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addhours)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$_.TimeRaised = ([datetime]$_.TimeRaised).AddHours(1).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')
```

First, cast the retrieved date string as a `[datetime]` object. Then add an hour using `AddHours(1)`. Then format your date string.

**EDIT:**

Your later comments show a different format than in the original question. You can parse that format and apply the same methods:

```
$_.TimeRaised = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.TimeRaised,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss',[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture).AddHours(1).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')
```

Comment: Its working on my Windows 10 machine but not working on Server, Both have Powershell 5.1 installed. Below is the error-
______________
Cannot convert value "13/04/2020 06:31:53" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String 
was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:5 char:36
+ ... ts.csv | % {$_.TimeRaised = ([datetime]$_.TimeRaised).AddHours(1).ToS ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastParseTargetInvocationWithFormatProvider

Comment: Your post shows `09-04-202 05:12` as the format. You will need to parse to accept your changed format. `$_.TimeRaised = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.TimeRaised,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss',[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture).AddHours(1).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')`

Comment: I got your point, thanks for correcting me. Thank you so very much..

Answer (score 0):

Use the static method `[datetime]::ParseExact()` to parse your string in the format `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm`, then add one hour with another static method `[datetime]::AddHours()`. I also added the missing `0` to your date year so it becomes `09-04-2020 05:12` instead of `09-04-202 05:12`. You can use `[datetime] | Get-Member -Static` to find these static methods.

```
Import-Csv -Path .\data.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $date = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Timeraised, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", $null)
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Timeraised = $date.AddHours(1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path .\output.csv -NoTypeInformation -UseQuotes Never
# Remove -UseQuotes Never if you are not using PowerShell 7
```

Or with `foreach` enumeration instead of `Foreach-Object`:

```
& {
    foreach ($row in Import-Csv -Path .\data.csv)
    {
        $date = [datetime]::ParseExact($row.Timeraised, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", $null)
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Timeraised = $date.AddHours(1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path .\output.csv -NoTypeInformation -UseQuotes Never
# Remove -UseQuotes Never if you are not using PowerShell 7
```

Which will give the following output CSV:

```
Timeraised
9/04/2020 6:12
```

The above also uses these Cmdlets for importing and exporting CSV files:

- [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7)
- [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7).

You can also have a look at the MSDN documentation for the above .NET methods:

- [`System.DateTime.ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8)
- [`System.DateTime.AddHours()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addhours?view=netframework-4.8)